# why can't my odering and list_view go together with fieldsets in django admin class

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-admin

I'm trying to organize my admin page. I tried to use `list_display` to show the columns, and `fieldsets` to organize the section.

admin.py

```py
class PencilManugacturerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ordering = ['manufacturer_name']
    list_display = ['manufacturer_name', 'id']
    fieldsets = [("Manufacturer", {'fields': ["manufacturer_name"]})]
```

models.py

```
class PencilManufacturer(models.Model):
    manufacturer_for_type = models.ForeignKey(PencilType, default=1, verbose_name="Type", on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)
    manufacturer_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    manufacturer_description = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    manufacturer_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.manufacturer_name

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['manufacturer_name']
```

I expect to have my admin page to have columns and the section when I add data. If I don't comment out the `fieldsets` (and leave the 2 others active), or the `ordering` and `list_display` (and leave the `fieldsets` active), it will show these errors:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\QuanPham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\QuanPham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\QuanPham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\QuanPham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\QuanPham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 77, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[0](_exception[1]).with_traceback(_exception[2])
  File "C:\Users\QuanPham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\QuanPham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\QuanPham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 122, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "C:\Users\QuanPham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\apps.py", line 24, in ready
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "C:\Users\QuanPham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\__init__.py", line 26, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
  File "C:\Users\QuanPham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 47, in autodiscover_modules
    import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "C:\Users\QuanPham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 724, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 860, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 791, in source_to_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<string>", line None
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation (admin.py, line 18)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\QuanPham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\QuanPham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\QuanPham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\QuanPham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 60, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\QuanPham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\QuanPham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 95, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "C:\Users\QuanPham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 102, in run
    autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
  File "C:\Users\QuanPham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 577, in run_with_reloader
    start_django(reloader, main_func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\QuanPham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 562, in start_django
    reloader.run(django_main_thread)
  File "C:\Users\QuanPham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 280, in run
    self.run_loop()
  File "C:\Users\QuanPham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 286, in run_loop
    next(ticker)
  File "C:\Users\QuanPham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 326, in tick
    for filepath, mtime in self.snapshot_files():
  File "C:\Users\QuanPham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 342, in snapshot_files
    for file in self.watched_files():
  File "C:\Users\QuanPham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 241, in watched_files
    yield from iter_all_python_module_files()
  File "C:\Users\QuanPham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 103, in iter_all_python_module_files
    return iter_modules_and_files(modules, frozenset(_error_files))
  File "C:\Users\QuanPham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 128, in iter_modules_and_files
    if not path.exists():
  File "C:\Users\QuanPham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\pathlib.py", line 1339, in exists
    self.stat()
  File "C:\Users\QuanPham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\pathlib.py", line 1161, in stat
    return self._accessor.stat(self)
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '<frozen importlib._bootstrap>'
```

Comment: Please first fix this error 'inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation (admin.py, line 18)'

Comment: The problem is that error should not be there. If I comment out some line of code, it works, the problem only occurs when all of the code are not commented. I just don't understand why it throws out so much errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be some special character on the `fieldsets` line, delete it and rewrite and it works.